# How to overlay progress bar line over border of progress point?

Tags: html, css, progress-bar, markup, tracker

So I am working on a progress wizard with steps, and I am having a hard time with trying to get a certain look with the progress bar running into the rounded progress steps. Here is my HTML/CSS on Copepen:

http://codepen.io/heysharybobbins/pen/yymXbK

Ultimately, the goal is to have the gray and/or green progress line merge directly into the solid-circle progress step (dark gray or green). Right now, the gray or green progress line stops at the border which is set on the progress step circle:

[image]
[image]

The end goal is for it to look like this PSD example:

[image]

http://codepen.io/heysharybobbins/pen/yymXbK

```css
.container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.progress-wrap {
  height: 16px;
  background: #e4e4e4;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.progress-wizard {
  padding: 0 0 10px 0;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.progress-wizard li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16%;
  height: 36px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: -19px;
  line-height: 75px;
  border-top: 4px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fff;
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 1 !important;
}

.progress-wizard li:before {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  text-indent: 0;
  left: -webkit-calc(50% - 9.5px);
  left: -moz-calc(50% - 9.5px);
  left: -ms-calc(50% - 9.5px);
  left: -o-calc(50% - 9.5px);
  left: calc(50% - 9.5px);
}

.progress-wizard li.done {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.progress-wizard li.done:before {
  content: "✔" !important;
  color: white !important;
  text-shadow: none !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  top: -19px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 19px;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 0 #ccc;
}

.progress-wizard li.todo {
  font-size: 12px;
  border-top-color: #ccc;
  position: relative;
  color: #999;
}

.progress-wizard li.todo:before {
  content: "\2B24";
  font-size: 17.1px;
  top: -22px;
  line-height: 18.05px;
}

.progress-wizard li.done {
  color: #8c9c58;
  border-top-color: #8c9c58;
}

.progress-wizard li.done:before {
  color: white;
  background-color: #8c9c58;
  border: 5px solid #e4e4e4;
  position: relative;
  top: -22px;
}

.progress-wizard li.todo:before {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 5px solid #e4e4e4;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 0 #ccc;
  border-radius: 60px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.progress-wizard li.stepone:before {
  color: #999;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 white;
  content: "1";
}

.progress-wizard li.steptwo:before {
  color: #999;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 white;
  content: "2";
}

.progress-wizard li.stepthree:before {
  color: #999;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 white;
  content: "3";
}

.progress-wizard li.stepfour:before {
  color: #999;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 white;
  content: "4";
}

.progress-wizard li.stepfive:before {
  color: #999;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 white;
  content: "5";
}

.progress-wizard li.stepsix:before {
  color: #999;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 white;
  content: "6";
}

.progress-wizard li.current {
  color: #93b5d3;
}

.progress-wizard li.current:before {
  background: #93b5d3;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="progress-wrap">
  <ol class="progress-wizard">
    <li class="progress-point done stepone">Information</li><li class="progress-point current todo steptwo">Related Items</li><li class="progress-point todo stepthree">Access</li><li class="progress-point todo stepfour">Uploads</li><li class="progress-point todo stepfive">Availability</li><li class="progress-point todo stepsix">Review</li>
  </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

I was thinking in order to solve this it would have something to do with the z-index of the pseudo elements and parent of the pseudo elements, but I have tried a couple things and have had no luck. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I am looking over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could this be it?

```
.progress-wizard li.done:after {
  content: " ";
  background-color: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  padding-right: 47px;
  left: 107px;
  height: 4px;

}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBVxje

**EDIT:**

Just saw a small problem. You have to add this :after element only to the last done element. Otherwise it overlays the progress bar. Is it fine? It can be removed using JS.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I am going to test your solution shortly. I will let you know if it works out!

Comment: This did work as intended, but with the caveat that you mentioned in your edit about overlaying the numbers/check marks in the progress bar, which isn't desired. I did however change some of the code you provided to create the illusion of the progress bar overlaying the progress points left side border. I then, at least as a temporary solution, albeit less pretty from a markup perspective, added spans inside the <li>'s and created the right progress bar overlay. Not the prettiest solution, but it might work until I figure something better out. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks Alexey! I am still fairly new to using Stack Overflow. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

**In Bootstrap**

```
.progress-wizard li:before {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  text-indent: 0;
  left: -webkit-calc(50% - 9.5px);
  left: -moz-calc(50% - 9.5px);
  left: -ms-calc(50% - 9.5px);
  left: -o-calc(50% - 9.5px);
  left: calc(50% - 9.5px);
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```